# SAS XML mapping - with multiple XML files

Tags: mysql, xml, xml-parsing, extract, sas

I would like to know how to use SAS XML Mapping with multiple XML files

The code below is what I use to extract one xml file (data1.xml) using mapping from SAS XML Mapper (global.map) I was able to get the final extracted dataset "GlobalDecision" ...

```
filename  data1 'c:\data1.xml';
filename  SXLEMAP 'c:\global.map';
libname   data1 xml xmlmap=SXLEMAP access=READONLY;

proc datasets lib=data1; quit;

DATA GlobalDecision; SET data1.GlobalDecision; run;
```

However my XML is stored in mySQL for each ID,  each record has the xml text ( uncompressed) named "var_x" , so if I want to extract say 10 records,  I would pull my dataset using this code below

```
proc sql; create table x as select ID, var_x from table1 limit 10 ;quit;
```

My question is how can I incorporate my x table to the Mapping code above to get the "GlobalDecision" final table that would give me 10 records with all values extracted.

Thank you!!

Comment: It might help if you provide an example of what a row of data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

One row of data ( "var_x" ) would have xml that looks like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AResponse>
      <GenerationTime>20120301120031</GenerationTime>
      <CodeVersion>4.34.1</CodeVersion>
      <RequestVersion>3.0</RequestVersion>
      <TransactionId>156368133</TransactionId>
      <TrackHash>2211bc09ee00c45fe6ffa61648f33d3e</TrackHash>
      <Id>1125051053</Id>
      <Response>   
        <GlobalDecision>
          <Decision>N</Decision>
          <Mcost>0</Mcost>
          <LC>A1</LC>
          <Check>A1</Check>
          <IDet>D6</IDet>
          <ReferBuckets>
            <Bucket>P1</Bucket>
          </ReferBuckets>
 </GlobalDecision>
  </Response>
</AResponse>
```